# Prevent wx.StaticBitmap from resizing

Tags: python, bitmap, wxpython, autoresize, wxwidgets

This is related to wxPython.

I often set new `wx.Bitmap`s to a `wx.StaticBitmap` control. Every time I do this, the control is resized to fit the image size.

Is there a way to keep the size of the `wx.StaticBitmap` control when setting a new `wx.Bitmap`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do what I did in my [simple image viewer](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/26/creating-a-simple-photo-viewer-with-wxpython/) which was scale the image down.

```
# scale the image, preserving the aspect ratio
self.PhotoMaxSize = 240
img = wx.Image(filepath, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
W = img.GetWidth()
H = img.GetHeight()
if W > H:
    NewW = self.PhotoMaxSize
    NewH = self.PhotoMaxSize * H / W
else:
    NewH = self.PhotoMaxSize
    NewW = self.PhotoMaxSize * W / H
img = img.Scale(NewW,NewH)
self.imageCtrl.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(img))
```

I thought that was pretty effective where imageCtrl is a wx.StaticBitmap

Comment: I hoped there would be a way to to this without editing the image, because I think it should be possible.

Comment: This doesn't edit the image. It only scales it down to fit onscreen. All photo viewers do something like this. They either scale it down or make thumbnails. Most images nowadays are higher resolution than most monitors.

Comment: I think we talk at cross-purposes. I already have small images and don't wanted StaticBitmap to change the widget size when a Bitmap is set. Anyways, I decided to do my own painting on a Panel, cause this eliminates flicker, too.